# Why does Mono locks up on regex

Tags: regex, mono

This is the line mono on linux locks up (i am using 2.6.4 VM distro on the official site)

```
var match = Regex.Match(sz, linkPattern);
```

The string is this which gets the link and the title.

```
var linkPattern = @"<\ba\b[^\>]*\bhref\b*=\b*""([^""\>]*)""[^\>]*\btitle\b*=\b*""([^""\>]*) by [^""\>]*""";
```

When mono hits that line it doesnt crash, throw an exception or anything. Using tops i see mono using 96% of the CPU. I dont know how long the string is. I suspect its <8kb (i tested a different url) and it has been a few minutes since i ran the code so something must be broken.

Comment: Seriously. You should use a parser. I really don't know what is so hard to understand about this simple fact, that "how to do HTML parsing with regex"-questions must be asked by seasoned users here as well. :-\

Comment: Is this a valid regexp? What does \b* mean? Also, more data about the problem could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Too many `\b`'s" was my first reaction. But really:

`\b` means word boundary. In my opinion, `<\ba` and `<a` should be identical. Also, `\b*` therefore would mean "optional repetition of word boundaries", which sounds rather confusing.

I guess I've never used `\b` at all, and used `\s?` or `\s*` instead.

Did you try a different regex engine (Perl, PHP) to determine whether the lockup is due to Mono?

Comment: You're right, the `\b` in `<\ba` is pointless.  As for `\b*`, it looks like it's supposed to be `\s*`: zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: I dont know why i wrote that, it was old code but \b* was the problem and \s* is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs in Mono's regex implementation that can cause it to recurse infinitely.  Probably the only fix is to rewrite your pattern to be a simpler regular expression, or not use regular expressions for this task.

You may also want to file a bug.  I think there is a Google Summer of Code student currently working on Mono's regular expression engine.